# Process Records EOF

Tags: email, ms-access, vba

Wondering if someone might be able to help me solve this issue.  Have an Access database where I want to send an email for each "Submit" box that is checked is checked.  Have tried several thing and either get 1 record processed before the code stops or will give me several emails for the same record without moving on.  Any help with where I am missing the boat would be much appreciated.  Below is what I have for the code:

```
Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Set r = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [CIs_All_Statuses] WHERE [Submit] = True")
    If r.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("No records selected")
    GoTo Done
    Else
    End If

r.MoveFirst
i = 1

Begin:
Do Until r.EOF = True

product = r![Product Name]
serial = r![Serial Number]
agency = r![Company]
User = r![Used By]
Submit = r![Submit]
Processed = r![Processed]

If Processed = True Then
    r.Edit
    r("Submit").Value = False
    r.Update
    r.MoveNext
    GoTo Begin
Else
End If

r.Edit
r("Processed").Value = True
r.Update

r.Edit
r("Submit").Value = False
r.Update

r.MoveNext

Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmailItem As MailItem
' prevent 429 error, if outlook not open
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
End If

Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With oEmailItem
.To = "@email.com"
.CC = Me.Used_By
.Subject = "EmailTicket: [Subject]"
.Body = "Equipment to be verified:" & Space(2) & product & vbCrLf & "Serial Number:" & Space(2) & serial & vbCrLf & "Agency:" & Space(2) & agency & vbCrLf & "User Name:" & Space(2) & User & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "By inserting the user name in the CC line the Customer Information on the Incident Customer tab will be auto-completed.  ONLY append information to the end of the SUBJECT LINE"

.Display
End With

r.MoveNext

Check:
Do While r.EOF = False

    NextComputer = r![Serial Number]
    If (serial = NextComputer) Then
        r.Edit
        r("Submit").Value = False
        r.Update
        r.Edit
        r("Processed").Value = True
        r.Update
        r.MoveNext
        GoTo Check
        Else
        r.MovePrevious
        End If
Loop
r.MovePrevious

Loop
r.Close
Set r = Nothing

Done:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is - among other things - the `GoTo Check`.

Remove that and rebuild your loop.
Also, you only need one `.Edit` and `.Update` for each record.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  They pointed me in right direction!  I have it squared away and running.  I am sure the code is not as clean as it could be...still trying to get a feel for how al this works.